# See element onHover in mapped list with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list I want an x icon to appear when user hovers over the item. Currently when user hovers over 1 item the x icon appears on all items in the list. How can I identify just 1 element from the list?

component

```
const [delWatchlist, setDelWatchlist] = useState(false);


                    <UncontrolledDropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle} className="watchlist-dropdown">
                        <DropdownToggle caret>
                        {selected}
                            </DropdownToggle>
                        <DropdownMenu>
                            <DropdownItem onClick={() => createForm()}>Create new list</DropdownItem>
                            <DropdownItem onClick={() => renameForm()}>Rename</DropdownItem>
                            <DropdownItem onClick={() => clearForm()}>Clear list</DropdownItem>
                            <DropdownItem divider />
                            {watchlists.map((value, index) => (
                                <DropdownItem value={index} key={value} onClick={() => updateSelected(index)} onMouseEnter={() => setDelWatchlist(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setDelWatchlist(false)}>
                                    <span className="title-watchlists">
                                        {value}
                                    </span>
                                    {delWatchlist && (
                                    <i className="mdi mdi-close-box-outline icon-watchlists" />
                                    )}
                                </DropdownItem>
                            ))}
                        </DropdownMenu>
                    </UncontrolledDropdown>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an identifier in `delWatchlist`.
You could use `value`, if it is unique. `index` works, too.

```
const [delWatchlist, setDelWatchlist] = useState(undefined);

// ...

{watchlists.map((value, index) => (
  <DropdownItem
    value={index}
    key={value}
    onClick={() => updateSelected(index)}
    onMouseEnter={() => setDelWatchlist(index)}
    onMouseLeave={() => setDelWatchlist(current => current === index ? undefined : current)}> // Make sure to only unset itself
    <span className="title-watchlists">{value}</span>
    {delWatchlist === index && (
      <i className="mdi mdi-close-box-outline icon-watchlists" />
    )}
  </DropdownItem>
))}
```